# How do I delete trailing zeros on floats without rounding in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to clear trailing zeros on floats without rounding?  I need to only display relevant decimal places.

For example, if I have 0.5, I need it to show 0.5, not 0.500000.  If I have 2.58328, I want to display 2.58328.  If I have 3, I want to display 3, not 3.0000000.  Basically, I need the amount of decimal places to change.

Comment: Are you talking about when printing or assigning the float value to a label or something? Clarify what you have and what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter, to be honest.  Ideally, it'd be when it printed, and I'd still like it to be available in a numerical format (so I don't have to turn it into a string for the formatting and then back out of it).  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 29):

Use the following:

```
NSString* floatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", myFloat];
```

Comment: This displays the real value of a float, it shows up to 6 digits before rounding, if you want to display more digits you have to specify it yourself like %.10g

Comment: so simple, looks great.

Comment: It works fine but it gives Exponential form for large numbers & i don't want that.. Any solution to that?

Comment: @Sam If you are receiving exponential form have you tried using `%g` or `%G`? One causes it the other won't.

Comment: WOW! didn't know this before

Answer (score 27):

`NSNumberFormatter` is the way to go:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 20;

NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:@1.20];
NSLog(@"%@", result);

result = [formatter stringFromNumber:@0.00031];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

This will print:

```
1.2
0.00031
```